# Datos relacionados laravel

Tags: laravel, sql, eloquent

Buenas estoy sacando en una vista esto:

```
$productos = Producto::where('categoria', $cat)->where('subcategoria', $sub)->get();
```

Y lo imprimo así en la vista:

```
@foreach ($productos as $pro)    
            <div class="col-4 catProduct">
                <div class="col-12 bordeCajon">
                    @if ($pro->novedad == 1)
                        <div class="nEntrada">NOVEDAD</div> 
                    @endif

                    @if ($pro->pvpAntes == null)     
                    @else
                        <div class="oferta">OFERTA!</div>
                    @endif   
                    <div class="minHei">
                        <img src="{{ asset("images/productos/camas/{$pro->imagen}") }}" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="paddingProducto">
                        <h2>{{ $pro->marca }}</h2>
                        <h3>{{ $pro->producto }}</h3>
                        <div class="dividerProd"></div>
                        <ul>
                          <!-- aqui las opciones -->
                        </ul>
                        <h4>{{ $pro->pvpAhora }} <span>€</span></h4>

                        @if ($pro->pvpAntes == null)     
                        @else
                            <div class="pvpAntes">{{ $pro->pvpAntes }} <span>€</span></div>
                        @endif 
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btnForm pull-right">VER PRODUCTO</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
```

Bien esto sale de una tabla que se llama productos y contiene un campo `id`
Tengo otra tabla que se llama opciones que contiene una columna que se llama `producto`.

Lo que quiero es que donde pone en el foreach `aqui las opciones` quiero que me imprima de la tabla opciones, todas las opciones relacionadas con `id` de producto de la tabla productos.

**Modelo producto**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Producto extends Model
{
    //
}
```

**Modelo opcion**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Opcion extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Los modelos los tengo vacios ya que soy nuevo en Laravel y hasta día de hoy me a bastado con los controladores y las rutas no he necesitado nuca esto.

Como puede que en la tabla opciones tenga muchas opciones para un producto entiendo que estamos hablando de que la `relación es de 1 a muchos`.

En mi controlador he probado de la siguiente forma:

```
$records = DB::table('opciones')
             ->join('productos', 'productos.id', '=', 'opciones.producto')->get();
```

Pero en todos los productos me imprime todas las opciones.

Comment: Si exacto @BetaM

Comment: He probado del siguiente modo @BetaM `$records = DB::table('opciones')
             ->join('productos', 'productos.id', '=', 'opciones.producto')->get();`  Pero en todos los productos me imprime todas las opciones

Comment: hola @BetaM ya modifique la pregunta, los modelos no los e gastado nunca así que los tengo vacios, espero este más clara la pregunta ahora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La relación que tienes es de 1:Muchos Donde: un producto tiene muchas opciones

Dado eso entonces en tus modelos debes declarar las siguientes relaciones:

Modelo Producto:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Producto extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = "Llave primaria de este modelo";
    protected $table = 'nombre de la tabla';
    public function opciones()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Opcion::class, "llave foránea", "llave primaria");
    }
}
```

Modelo Opcion:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Opcion extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = "Llave primaria de este modelo";
    protected $table = 'nombre de la tabla';
    public function producto()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Producto::class, "llave foranea");
    }
}
```

Como los nombres de tus tablas, nombres de las llaves primarias y foráneas no cumplen las convenciones de Laravel, entonces deberás usar:

- La propiedad $primarykey para declarar el nombre de la llave primaria en cada modelo
- La propiedad $table para declarar en cada modelo el nombre de la tabla con la cual esta vinculado
- Revisa en los métodos hasMany y belongsTo el segundo y tercer parámetro que pasé para que Eloquent pueda trabajar con tus tablas
- Bien ahora basándome en uno de los comentarios, para obtener todas las opciones de un producto deberás hacer lo siguiente:

  ```
    $producto = Producto::with('opciones')->findOrFail($idProducto);
  ```

Ahora bien, los modelos en Eloquent, piden se cumplan ciertas convenciones y en caso de no estar presentes entonces se deben configurar ciertos parámetros, para eso

**Recomiendo leas**

- https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions
- https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta funciona perfecto y por fin lo entiendo, gracias @BetaM

Comment: Hola @BetaM mira si puedes mirar esto, me esta volviendo loco y ya no se si lo estoy haciendo bien. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/360559/no-entiendo-bien-el-eloquent-laravel

Answer (score 1):

Primero: tenés que tener la relación bien definida en la base de datos, tu campo opciones.producto debería ser opciones.product_id, siempre son recomendables los nombres en ingles para que Laravel trabaje por convención.

Segundo: En el Model de productos definís la relación, luego en blade sólo la utilizas. Por ejemplo, tengo una tabla specialties y otra doctors, por cada specialty tengo varios doctores, entonces en la tabla doctors tengo un campo specialty_id que los vincula, entonces en el Model de Specialty defino la relación:

```
public function doctors()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Doctor','specialty_id');
}
```

Luego, a blade envío las specialties y hago:

```
@foreach ($specialties as $specialty)
   @foreach ($specialty->doctors as $doctor)

    <!-- aqui las opciones -->

  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Si no entendí mal tenés que hacer lo mismo con tus tablas, saludos.