# No entiendo bien el eloquent Laravel

Tags: laravel

pregunta sobre Eloquent.

Tengo tres tablas.

**1)productos**

```
| -id | categoria | subcategoria | producto | etc.. |
```

**2)categorias**

```
| -id | nombre |  etc.. |
```

**3)subcategorias**

```
  | -id | categoria | nombre | etc.. |
```

---

**Modelo Producto**

```
protected $table = 'productos';

public function categorias()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Categoria', 'id');
}
```

**Modelo Categoria**

```
protected $table = 'categorias';


public function subcategorias()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategoria', 'categoria_id');
}


public function productos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Producto', 'categoria');
}
```

**Modelo Subcategoria**

```
 protected $table = 'subcategorias';

    public function categoria()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categoria', 'id');
    }
```

---

En la vista principal tengo un listado con las categorías.
Para acceder a ellas lo hago de la siguiente forma:

Ruta:

```
Route::get('catalogo/{id}/', "Web@verCategoria")->name('web.catalogo');
```

Controlador:

```
public function verCategoria($id)
    {
        $category= Categoria::findOrFail($id);
        return view("catalogo")->with(["categorias" => $this->categorias,
                                       "category" => $category]);
    }
```

Link:

```
{{ route('web.catalogo', ['id' => $cat->id]) }}
```

Una vez estoy viendo la categoría me muestra todas las subcategorias de este modo:

```
 @foreach ($category->subcategorias as $subcate)
    <div class="col-3 subCa">
      <img src="{{ asset("images/productos/camas/{$subcate->imagen}") }}" alt="">
      <div class="subCa43">
          <h3>{{ $subcate->nombre }}</h3>
          <p>{{ Str::limit($subcate->descripcion, 100) }}</p>
          <div class="margenBTN">
              <a href="**Aquí no se como crear la ruta**">SABER MÁS</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

Cada subcategoria tiene un botón que al darle me tiene que dar los productos que tiene esa subcategoria y a la vez la categoría.

Una vez que me salgan los porductos, cada producto tendrá un botón para ver sus detalles en otra vista. Al hacerlo todo con los modelos ando un poco perdido.

No se como hacer esto en el modelo ni en la ruta.... :S